# error adding ruby code on a structure

Tags: ruby

I have a structure defined in 'strct'. Its possible to add some ruby code like the next example?

```
  def strct(i)
        {
          "mwdata": [
       i.times do //incorrect
            {
              "mwtype": "cell",
              "mwsize": [
                1,
                3
              ],
              "mwdata": [
                10,
                23,
                199
              ]
            }
        end //incorrect
          ]
        }
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply arrays by using `*`, but this will create an Array of references to the same Hash object, changing one, changes all of them. (as @mudasobwa pointed out in the comments)

```
def strct(i)
  { "mwdata": [ {...} ] * i }
end
```

It's also possible to use tap:

```
def strct(i)
  { "mwdata" => [].tap do |array|
      i.times do 
        array << { .... }
      end
    end
  }
end
```

Or inject:

```
def strct(i)
  { "mwdata" => 1.upto(i).inject([]) do |array|
      array << { .... }
    end
  }
end
```

**Note**

I understand the reason for this question, as I have often found myself doing something like:

```
def strct(i)
  result = { "foo" => [] }
  i.times do
    result["foo"] << "Something #{i}"
  end
  result
end
```

Quick googling gave me this: [hash_builder.rb](https://gist.github.com/nileshtrivedi/1391902) that works like jsonbuilder and can be used to create hash "templates".

Comment: Please aware that these two snippets **are not equivalent**. The former creates the only hash, referenced `i` times, while the latter creates `i` different hashes. If the OP is going to mutate nested hashes, this is very significant difference.

Comment: @mudasobwa That's true.